# Synaptic package manager problems

Tags: package-management, files, synaptic

Synaptic Package Manager fails, printing this message on startup:

```
E: ファイル  をオープンできませんでした - open (2: そのようなファイルやディレクトリはありません)
E: _cache->open() failed, please report.
```

The English version of this error message is:

```
E: Failed to open file - open (2: No such file or directory)
E: _cache->open() failed, please report.

$ sudo dpkg --configure -a  
$ sudo apt-get install -f  
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
```

How do I correct this problem?

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get update` , `sudo dpkg --configure -a` , `sudo apt-get install -f` and add output of these commands to question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sudo cp -r /var/lib/apt/lists /var/lib/apt/lists.bak
sudo rm -vf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

and then again

```
sudo apt update
```

Tell us if it works. The location of `/var/lib/apt/lists` contains automatically downloaded deb files.

Comment: $ sudo apt update
取得:54 http://ftp.riken.jp/pub/Linux/ubuntu xenial-backports/multiverse DEP-11 64x64 Icons [29 B]
39.3 MB を 10秒 で取得しました (3,919 kB/s)                                    

** (appstreamcli:1223): CRITICAL **: Error while moving old database out of the way.
AppStream cache update failed.
パッケージリストを読み込んでいます... 完了
依存関係ツリーを作成しています       
状態情報を読み取っています... 完了
アップグレードできるパッケージが 4 個あります。表示するには 'apt list --upgradable' を実行してください。